# Embedded Slideshow/Image Viewer?

Tags: javascript, css, image-viewer

I've run across this sort of thing on multiple websites and was wondering what it was called, does anyone know? [Here's a screenshot.](http://twitpic.com/h77i/full)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's [lightbox](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox/).

**Edit:** Or [Lightbox 2](http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Lightbox (or clone),

Look at this [Lightbox Clone List](http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/), I personally like the [jQuery lightBox plugin](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)...